Cannot perform inifinite scroll using playwright on certain website
I am crawling https://kick.com/browse/categories where every time you scroll it loads new cards of a category. I have tried multiple methods using playwright but none of them worked.
Would appreciate any suggestions.
I have tried using Chrome debugger console and it worked fine. Each time I ran div.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight); document.documentElement.outerHTML;, the returned html gets longer and longer, and there will be more and more href links with /category/.
However, with the following playwright approaches, I always get the exact same HTML. The loaded HTML (printed by page.conent()) after scrolling will always contain 64 href links to the available categories, which I assume is the initially loaded content.
Here is how I setup the web driver
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(
            args=[f"--proxy-server={PROXY}"], headless=True, executable_path=CHROME
        )
        context = await browser.new_context(
            user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        )
        page = await context.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://kick.com/browse/categories")

What I have tried:

scroll using scrollTo

PAGE_DOWN_JS = """
div = document.querySelector('#main-container');
div.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
"""
        await page.wait_for_selector("#main-container")
        for _ in range(100):
            await page.evaluate(PAGE_DOWN_JS)
            await page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle", timeout=120000)


sending PageDown key

        await page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle", timeout=60000)
        for _ in range(100):  # Adjust the range according to how much you want to scroll
        await page.keyboard.press("PageDown")


mouse wheel

        await page.mouse.wheel(0, 150000)
        time.sleep(10)


scrolling to locator which points to the bottom of the list

        cards = page.locator("div.flex.flex-col.items-start")
        print(f"found {await cards.count()} cards")
        all_cards = await cards.all()
        await all_cards[-1].scroll_into_view_if_needed()
        cards = page.locator("div.flex.flex-col.items-start")


See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76878905/1831456

I have identified the issue with your code snippet — the code doesn't wait for the new scrolled-down page (i.e. new content) to be fully loaded. I also added an assert to compare the new contents after each scroll down:
import asyncio
import time
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

PAGE_DOWN_JS = """
div = document.querySelector('#main-container');
div.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
"""

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = await browser.new_context()
        page = await context.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://kick.com/browse/categories")

        await page.wait_for_selector("#main-container")

        prev_content = ""
        for _ in range(3):
            await page.evaluate(PAGE_DOWN_JS)
            # await page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle", timeout=120000)
            await page.wait_for_timeout(5000)  # new
            time.sleep(5)  # new
            content = await page.content()
            assert content != prev_content
            prev_content = content

        content = await page.content()
        print(content)
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())

You can also check if the page is reached to the end of the page or not:
prev_content = ""
prev_scroll_height = 0
while True:
    await page.evaluate(PAGE_DOWN_JS)
    await page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
    scroll_height = await page.evaluate(
        'document.querySelector("#main-container").scrollHeight'
    )

    if scroll_height == prev_scroll_height:
        break
    prev_scroll_height = scroll_height

    content = await page.content()
    assert content != prev_content
    prev_content = content


Thanks! Now that it's loading I've find the real problem. When it makes a request to load more content, it hits 403 forbidden because it says javascript or cookies is not enabled, although I did enable them. posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79000090/playwright-cookies-and-enabled-javascript-not-being-recognized-by-website.

@GinniSong I will look into that. BTW, if this answer has solved your question, you can accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
