playwright cannot bypass cloudflare bot detection even adding cookies and user agents
I'm trying to crawl https://kick.com/browse/categories with playwright which has infinite scroll. I've tried evaluating the below js code and wait for an extended period for loading. I'm turning off headless for easier visual. In the browser the webpage can be scrolled for a few times. When it reaches the end, and the website requests to load more content, the request fails with 403. It says that javascript or cookie is not enabled.

The same result shows when I turn on headless.
Edit: I just realized that the response html has title "Just a moment..." which I've seen in a cloudflare page html. The error probably comes from cloudflare rather than the actual site I'm crawling, which means that my script is detected as a bot. Trying to find what cookies/headers to use to bypass that.
response html: pastebin1
request html: pastebin2
Request: GET https://kick.com/api/v1/subcategories?limit=32&page=2 {'cluster': 'v1', 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"', 'referer': 'https://kick.com/browse/categories', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36', 'accept': 'application/json', 'sec-ch-ua': '"HeadlessChrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0'}

I've also tried:

add cookies in request header with page.set_extra_http_headers. The cookies come from chrome inspector > Network > request headers
replace sec-ch-ua in request header with the one I got from chrome.
use playwright-stealth. this doesn't work. when I turn on the stealth mode, for the website in question, the loaded page will be blank.

How else can I bypass the bot detection?
End edit
Below is my code:
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import time

# copied with cookie editor when opening the page with chrome
cookies = [
    {
        "domain": "kick.com",
        "expirationDate": 1726721839.170133,
        "name": "KP_UIDz-ssn",
        "path": "/",
        "value": "02drFYb8SXDKZm1tttHbDxrjgNuDdR4yBLOBCmEN9sCjbepNK6vZ1ESDUhPkXwwGDbuhype6dcvmnxsMesfoHNevNIZD4Htf8KWlaDjuN30u2N6SIIJciTgkEWG5nX8cWHWrf5qXLq8NU1SGriiT6yIfuTYvqEG3fvO1Kb"
    },
    {
        "domain": ".kick.com",
        "name": "__cf_bm",
        "path": "/",
        "value": "CmeY2iVdWeXaYGUuIDyRMRxDgMQjYhZcl3we_Qy8pW8-1726689886-1.0.1.1-mLpIWwhnp3_zmFV7.bmPiIafI7q_BdbQduJiSxKUcOOCFPV.3r3Yb.p36MT3Sa1Ubq2TCTVOuilQEV3X6u0kjw"
    },
    {
        "domain": ".kick.com",
        "name": "__stripe_mid",
        "path": "/",
        "value": "50b6ac3c-0cc6-44de-b64a-916706484819d40fd7"
    },
    {
        "domain": ".kick.com",
        "name": "__stripe_sid",
        "path": "/",
        "value": "2d4b8647-0a68-46f9-8921-e8ce26409063280566"
    }
]

PAGE_DOWN_JS = """
div = document.querySelector('#main-container');
div.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
"""
async def handle_response(response):
    # Get the response body as text
    html_content = await response.body()
    print(f"Response: {html_content.decode('utf-8')}")


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        # Launch the browser
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True, args=["--start-maximized"])
        context = await browser.new_context(user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
        await context.add_cookies(cookies)
        page = await context.new_page()

        # Navigate to the website
        await page.goto('https://kick.com/browse/categories')
        await page.wait_for_selector("#main-container")
        button = page.locator("div.flex.flex-row.items-center.justify-center.gap-2>button>>nth=0")
        await button.click()
        await page.screenshot(path="/Users/gxsong/kick/screenshot_before.png")

        page.on("console", lambda msg: print(f"Console [{msg.type}]: {msg.text}"))
        page.on("response", lambda response: asyncio.create_task(handle_response(response)))

        # Evaluate some JavaScript code on the page
        await page.evaluate('''
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                console.log('Scrolled! Current scroll position:', window.scrollY);
            });
        ''')
        for i in range(10):
            await page.evaluate(PAGE_DOWN_JS)
            time.sleep(10)

        await page.screenshot(path="/Users/gxsong/kick/screenshot.png")
        page_content = await page.content()
        # print(page_content)

        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())


I just realized that the response html has title "Just a moment..." which I've seen in a cloudflare page html. The error probably comes from cloudflare rather than the actual site I'm crawling, which means that my script is detected as a bot. Trying to find what cookies/headers to use to bypass that.
response html: https://pastebin.com/MBVygyRi
request html: https://pastebin.com/GWA6wr1i

You should take a look at Undetected Chromedriver (https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver).
